# Consolidating multiple AWS Classic Load Balancers into a single load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We currently use a single AWS classic load balancer per EC2. This was cost effective for not many EC2s but now we're a growing project, we have 8 Classic Load Balancers which is starting to cost more than we'd like

What could I do to consolidate these multiple load balancers into a single load balancer?

The current load balancers are only used to forward HTTP/HTTPs traffic to an EC2 that's registered against it

I have DNS A records setup to route to the load balancers

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all the details, you might be better creating a single application load balancer with multiple target groups, this way it's only one load balancer and then you have the segregation at target group level rather than load balancer level.

If you need http/s access to some pieces of infrastructure and app access to others then you might consider one network LB and one application LB.